# How to get HTML element using ViewChild?

Tags: angular, angular8

How to get whole HTML element using ViewChild?

I have tried:

```
   @ViewChild("mapContainer", { static: false }) mapContainer: HTMLElement;
```

Where 'd' is reference:

```
<div #mapContainer></div>
```

Comment: I want to work with d as HTMLElement type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this

```js
@ViewChild('mapContainer', { static: true }) map: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.map.nativeElement);
}
```

[Here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) you can read more about ViewChild.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ElementRef` with `ViewChild`,

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('mapContainer', {static: false})
private el: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){
    const element = this.el.nativeElement;
}
```